# hide if component exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Should I use ref in this case? I want to check if a component is rendered then use that as flag to do something else.

```
render(){
    {isSomeOtherCondition && <CustomComponent {...props} />}
    <div className={classnames({'hide': isCustomCompoentExist })} >hide this if CustomComponent is rendered</div>
}
```

Comment: You cannot tell whether it's rendered or not, but you can use the same condition it uses to hide/show.

Answer (score 0):

With the example provided, we already have a variable defining when `<CustomComponent>` is rendered. We can use `isSomeOtherCondition` to hide the `<div>` element.

```
render() {
    return (
       <div>
          {
             isSomeOtherCondition ?
                <CustomComponent {...props} /> : 
                <div>hide this if CustomComponent is rendered</div>
          }
       </div>
   );
}
```

So if `isSomeOtherCondition` is `true`, render `<CustomComponent />`. If `isSomeOtherCondition` happens to false, then we will render `<div>hide this if CustomComponent is rendered</div>`.